# Python networkx connect subgraph with a loose node

Tags: python, networkx

Let's say we have the following graph (please see below):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3), (1,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,10), (10,11), (5,7), (5,8), (8,9), (9,10)])
```

[image: Full graph]

At one moment there is a subgraph that consists of few interconnected nodes and one node that has no edges:

```
nx.draw(G.subgraph([1,2,3,11]), with_labels=True)
```

[image: Subgraph - incomplete]

Since all nodes of the incomplete subgraph come from the same full graph they can be connected (e.g. by a shortpath) what is presented on the following picture:

```
nx.draw(G.subgraph([1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11]), with_labels=True)
```

[image]

I wonder whether there is a `networkx` function that given a set (or any iterable of nodes) returns a subgraph that makes sure all nodes are connected. In other words (and case-specifically) I would like to get the list `[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11]` as an output of a function.

### Clarification edit

Since it seems that I'm being misunderstood I'm giving few more examples.

#### First example

```
G1 = nx.Graph()

G1.add_edges_from([(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (5,7), (5,8), (8,9), (9,10), (10,12), (10,11), (11,12)])

chosen_nodes = [1,2,3,12] # construct a subgraph based on those nodes

output_nodes = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,12]
```

Output nodes are those nodes that make the subgraph connected, i.e. there are no loose ends in the subgraph.

#### Second example

```
G2 = nx.Graph()

G2.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (4,6)])

chosen_nodes = [1,2,5]

output_nodes = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

#### Example 3

```
G3 = nx.Graph()

G3.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3), (3,5), (2,4), (4,5)])

chosen_nodes = [1,2,3]

output_nodes = [1,2,3]
```

In general there's is a function that based on `chosen_nodes` creates a subgraph in which all nodes are somehow connected (edges are taken from `graph`).

```
def get_connected_subgraph(graph, chosen_nodes):
    return output_nodes
```

Comment: You are looking for connected components; for a given graph `g`, `networkx.connected_components(g)` with return an iterator of all connected components, largest component first.

Comment: In my case `networkx.connected_components(G)` returns a generator with only one element (I can use `next()` only once then `IterationError` is raised). This element consists of all the nodes in `G`. The output should be the subset of those elements.

Comment: Did you call `connected_components` on your subgraph or the original graph?

Comment: I called `connected_components` on the original graph. Calling it on a subgraph results in a generator with two elements: `[{11}, {1,2,3}]`.

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: No, what I'm looking for is a list (or any other iterable) of nodes: `[1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11]`. This list shows what nodes I need to have to connect the loose end (in my case node `11`) with the connected part of the subgraph (`1, 2, 3`).

Comment: My understanding of your question led to the same answer @PaulBrodersen gave.  So I think we need some more clarification with some sample inputs you expect and what the outputs would be for those inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You additional examples make the problem much clearer. And it is an interesting problem, so very much worth the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve your goal is to compute all shortest paths between your chosen nodes, and then determine the set of the nodes forming these paths.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Find the subgraph G' induced on G, that
1) contain all nodes in a set of nodes V', and
2) is a connected component.

See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58076592/python-networkx-connect-subgraph-with-a-loose-node
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import itertools

def get_connected_subgraph(graph, v_prime):
    """Given a graph G=(V,E), and a vertex set V', find the V'', that
    1) is a superset of V', and
    2) when used to induce a subgraph on G forms a connected component.

    Arguments:
    ----------
    G : networkx.Graph object
        The full graph.
    v_prime : list
        The chosen vertex set.

    Returns:
    --------
    v_prime_prime : set
        The set of nodes fullfilling criteria 1) and 2).

    """
    vpp = set()
    for source, target in itertools.combinations(v_prime, 2):
        paths = nx.all_shortest_paths(graph, source, target)
        for path in paths:
            vpp = vpp.union(path)
    return vpp

def test_1():
    G1 = nx.Graph()
    G1.add_edges_from([(1,2), (1,3), (2,3), (2,4), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (5,7), (5,8), (8,9), (9,10), (10,12), (10,11), (11,12)])
    chosen_nodes = [1,2,3,12] # construct a subgraph based on those nodes
    output_nodes = [1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10,12]
    returned_nodes = get_connected_subgraph(G1, chosen_nodes)
    assert set(output_nodes) == returned_nodes

def test_2():
    G2 = nx.Graph()
    G2.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3), (3,4), (4,5), (5,6), (4,6)])
    chosen_nodes = [1,2,5]
    output_nodes = [1,2,3,4,5]
    returned_nodes = get_connected_subgraph(G2, chosen_nodes)
    assert set(output_nodes) == returned_nodes

def test_3():
    G3 = nx.Graph()
    G3.add_edges_from([(1,2), (2,3), (3,5), (2,4), (4,5)])
    chosen_nodes = [1,2,3]
    output_nodes = [1,2,3]
    returned_nodes = get_connected_subgraph(G3, chosen_nodes)
    assert set(output_nodes) == returned_nodes
```